# If a job that I applied to through a recruiter is reposted through another recruiter and the company's website, can/should I reapply?

Tags: recruitment, applications

I applied to a job posting through a recruiter. They told me they would submit my application and provide me feedback. They then fell off the map completely, and didn't respond to my follow ups.

The job is no longer posted with the original recruiter, but is now posted with a new recruiter. It has also remained posted on the company website for this entire time.

Assuming the original recruiter no longer has a contract with the employer, would I still be "locked-in" to the original recruiter? I don't know if my application was even submitted. If I did reapply would it be better to apply directly or through the new recruiter?

Answer (score 4):

In your case, I would suggest you could apply directly through the company website. It is faster that way because the company's HR or own recruiters will be processing your application directly. Furthermore, the company may even like it better that way because they don't have to pay the recruiting agency a fee.

In addition, the old recruiter from the third party staffing company never replied to you, and so, you don't know what is going on. As you said, he may not even submit your resume to the company due to some unknown reason.

Comment: The company might have an agreement with the recruiter that will prevent the company to hire you directly. It can also be possible the recruiter will help to sell you to the company (fixing up your cv, focus on what you can offer that the company need and more) dont look at recruiters as just en extra cost, they can provide something the company might not have by them self.

Comment: @MrZach, You are right. There are advantages of applying via staffing agencies as they can also keep your resume in the database, and send your resume to  other companies, where you may be a good match.

Answer (score 3):

You will find questions on this site where people try to by-pass recruiters they're already working with and apply to a firm directly. This is generally frowned upon, because the recruiter has done the work to generate the lead (it is literally their job) and now the poster is trying to cut them out.

*But* your relationship with the recruiter is a two way street, and if they fail to respond to your messages, to even let you know what state the application is in, then it seems pretty reasonable to apply directly.

Answer (score 0):

In Australia, particularly for Government jobs, you should only go through one recruitment agent per job.
The agent will ask if you have already applied.
I have been involved in recruitment processes, and if we get two resumes for the same candidate they don't get to proceed any further. The reason for this is that when there are 100's of candidates per job, you don't have time to read a second copy of every application.

Comment: OP never mentioned Australia and there's no country tag. Assuming is dangerous.

Comment: I wasn't assuming. I was giving context to my answer, because it might not be applicable everywhere else.